# How to generate url using ids from firebase

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-router

I have a firebase db as a backend. I have some data in db. I want to generate urls like  mywebsite.com/pages/%IDfromDB/. If this db contains this ID i wil generate mywebsite.com/pages/%IDfromDB/ and render component using data from db.

For example i have data in firebase like

```
-pages
--id1
--id2
--id3
--etc.
```

so when my website url is mywebsite.com/pages/id1 i will generate page with data from

```
-pages
--url
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with url parameters ([doc](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/url-params)) :

```
 <Route path="/:id" component={Component} />
```